# GNU octave graph

Tags: octave

I have plotted a simple velocity against time graph about vibration on GNU Octave and I would like to know the exact values when the time is 1 and 10s. I'm not very sure on this, please help me on this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow . StackOverflow is a site for questions on computer programming, for actual issues with code that you are running. I recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what's [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question is quite vague, please consider proving a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and data.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your time array `t` contains those exact values, and assuming your velocity array is `v`, you could use

`v(find(sum(t==[1 10].')))`

and put as many values into that bracketed vector as you need.

If `t` doesn't have those exact values, like `t = [0 0.9 10.1]`, check out the intelligent use of the `unique` function at this page

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/375710-find-nearest-value-to-specific-number